# Flyweight pattern - Memory footprint

Tags: python, python-2.7, design-patterns, ubuntu-14.04, flyweight-pattern

I'm learning Python and I've thought it would be a nice excuse to refresh my pattern knowledge and in that case, the Flyweight pattern.

I created two small programs, one that is not optimized and one is implementing the Flyweight pattern. For my tests purposes, I'm creating an army of 1'000'000 `Enemy` objects. Each enemy can be of three types (Soldier, Ninja or Chief) and I assign a motto to each type.

What I would like to check is that, with my un-optimized program, I get 1'000'000 enemies with, for each and everyone of them, a type and a "long" string containing the motto. 
With the optimized code, I'd like to create only three objects (`EnemyType`) matching each type and containing only 3 times the motto's strings. Then, I add a member to each `Enemy`, pointing to the desired `EnemyType`.

Now the code (excerpts only) :

1. Un-optimized program

   In this version, each enemy stores its type and motto.

   ```
   enemyList = []
   enemyTypes = {'Soldier' : 'Sir, yes sir!', 'Ninja' : 'Always behind you !', 'Chief' : 'Always behind ... lot of lines '}
   for i in range(1000000):
     randomPosX = 0 # random.choice(range(1000))
     randomPosY = 0 # random.choice(range(1000))
     randomTypeIndex = 0 # random.choice(range(0,len(enemyTypes)))
     enemyType = enemyTypes.keys()[randomTypeIndex]

     # Here, the type and motto are parameters of EACH enemy object.
     enemyList.append(Enemy(randomPosX, randomPosY, enemyType, enemyTypes[enemyType]))
   ```
2. Optimized program

   In this version, each enemy has a member of an `EnemyType` object that stores its type and motto. Only three instances of `EnemyType` are created and I should see the impact in my memory footprint.

   ```
   enemyList = []
   soldierEnemy = EnemyType('Soldier', 'Sir, yes sir!')         
   ninjaEnemy = EnemyType('Ninja', 'Always behind you !')
   chiefEnemy = EnemyType('Chief', 'Always behind ... lot of lines.')
   enemyTypes = {'Soldier' : soldierEnemy, 'Ninja' : ninjaEnemy, 'Chief' : chiefEnemy}

   enemyCount = {}

   for i in range(1000000):
   randomPosX = 0 # random.choice(range(1000))
   randomPosY = 0 # random.choice(range(1000))
   randomTypeIndex = 0 #random.choice(range(0,len(enemyTypes)))
   enemyType = enemyTypes.values()[randomTypeIndex]

   # Here, each enemy only has a reference on its type.
   enemyList.append(Enemy(randomPosX, randomPosY, enemyType))
   ```

Now I'm using this to get my memory footprint (at the very last lines before my application closes itself) :

```
import os
import psutil
...
# return the memory usage in MB
process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
print process.get_memory_info()[0] / float(2 ** 20)
```

My problem is that, I don't see any difference between the output of my two programs :

Optimized = **384.0859375 Mb**
Un-optimized = **383.40234375 Mb**

Is it the proper tool to get the memory footprint ? I'm new to Python so it could be a problem with my code but I checked my EnemyType objects in the second solution and I indeed have only three occurences. I therefore should have 3 motto strings instead of 1'000'000.

I've read about a tool called [Heapy](http://guppy-pe.sourceforge.net/#Heapy) for Python, would it be more accurate here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I could tell from the code in the question, in both cases you're just using references for the same small number of instances anyway.

Take the "unoptimized" version's:

```
enemyList.append(Enemy(randomPosX, randomPosY, enemyType, enemyTypes[enemyType]))
```

Indeed `enemyTypes[enemyType]` is a string, which might have made you think you have many instances of strings. But in reality, each of your objects has one of the *three same string objects*.

---

You can check this by comparing the `id`s of the members. Make a `set` of the ids, and see if it is larger than 3.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Seems so obvious now you said it :) I made the change, checked the id (I didn't know that existed, cool!) and indeed I only got 1 id in my set. I changed a few things and I can see a difference now. Thanks a lot mate!